# Hybris convert Product to VariantProduct

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, hybris-data-hub

I extract from an WebService several Products which I convert to ProductModel, however, some of these products are "variants".
I need to manually convert a ProductModel to VariantProductModel, is there any OOTB way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change an object from Type. This is partly because the datatype is tied into the `PK` of your object.

If you want to change the type, you will need to create a new instance of the variantProductModel, copy all  the fields and remove the original product